# Semantic role of subject of 'refuse'

Tags: semantics

What's the semantic role of the subject of the following sentence?

> He refused to dine with me.

Originally, I thought it might be that of 'agent', but how can someone 'do' a refusal? Some enlightenment would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not understanding your confusion about agency here. Somebody "does" a refusal by saying "I refuse to eat with you" (or some equlvalent).

Comment: Volitional agent. Refusal is a mental decision, involving will and often emotion. The volition is negative -- _refuse_ means _won't_, i.e, _will not_, the deontic sense of the modal _will_. If he won't do it, he refuses to.

Comment: @JohnLawler It appears you have written your answer in the wrong text box.

Comment: @user888379. Well, my confusion owed itself to the fact that a refusal is not a tangible action in the same way that kicking a football is. However, John Lawler's comment has eliminated my confusion.

Comment: It's fun being in a conversation where "deontic" gets deployed :)

Comment: This is trash, pure and simple.

Comment: Kinder to see it as naive. If he refused, he probably used his words. He said no.

Comment: *Refused* belongs to the smallish set of performative verbs. The mere act of saying them accomplishes the action.

Answer (score 2):

As John Lawler stated:

> Volitional agent. Refusal is a mental decision, involving will and often emotion. The volition is negative -- *refuse* means *won't,* i.e, *will not,* the deontic sense of the modal *will.* If he won't do it, he refuses to.

Comment: Please delete and re-submit as a Community Wiki.